# How to delete email after .csv attachment import to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this script that is working correctly except it doesn't pull the data from the most recent email, it only pulls it from the first one.  If someone could help me configure it to delete the email after it pulls the .csv attachment that would be perfect.

Thanks!

```
function importCSVFromGmail() { 
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('South Loop Report').getThreads(0,1);     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {                            
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    //parses content of csv to array
    var dataString = attachment.getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(dataString);

    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sh.clearContents().clearFormats();                                         
    //pastes array to sheet
    var lastRowValue = sh.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
       sh.getRange(i+lastRowValue+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    } 
  }

  //marks the Gmail message as read and unstars it (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();                                                          
  message.unstar();                                                            

}

//The code formats the code so it can be entered into the Google Script

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){ 
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +


      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +


      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;

  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("South Loop Report");
  label.deleteLabel();
  // Move the first message in your inbox to trash
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var firstMessage = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
  GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(firstMessage);
}
```

Again, code is working I just need it to delete the email after it processes the csv file so I can run an automated trigger for it to pull the attachment from the new email every 5 minutes.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your script works. For this script, you want to add a function for deleting the message.

  - You want to delete the message at the last in the function `importCSVFromGmail`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

Please add the following script in the function `importCSVFromGmail` like below. When you use this, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

From:

```
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();

}
```

To:

```
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added

}
```

#### Note:

- **In this modification, the message is completely deleted. So when you run the script, please be careful this. I recommend to use a sample message for testing.**
- In the function of `CSVToArray`, by `return( arrData );`, the script below `return( arrData );` is not run. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Users.messages: delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.